# Google Play "Downloader" Application

Tags: android, google-play

I've created an application which only purpose is to download the real full-featured application from a server of mine, ask the user to accept the permissions and install it.

I know that there are some regulations for the Apple App store about this kind of "downloader" applications, so i was wondering if there is any sort of policy or term of use that might be violated if i decide to upload this app to the Google Play store.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out: https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html

I believe what you are doing is ok, but would most likely be frowned upon by Google, as they want people to use the Play Store.

Quote from the article:

> Malicious scripts and password phishing scams are also prohibited on
>   Google Play, as are apps that cause users to unknowingly download or
>   install apps from sources outside of Google Play.

As long as your are informing the user of the download, and not trying to make money, you're good.